# How to run same method in separate thread without end

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've a project which have a static web browser in the method. I wanted the run this method(which including the web browser)in same time, without ending.
There is:

> 1 method 2 button 2 textbox

```
static webbrowser wb;

public static look(string address)
{
    wb = new webbrowser;
    wb.navigate(address);
}

button1.click()
{
    for(int i = 0;i <= converttoint32(textbox1.text);i++)
        look(textbox2.text);
}

button2.click()
{
    //close the threads.
}
```

<
I want to use separate threads to create new webbrowser. They should continue until the button2.click.

eg. when clicked to button1 method will create web browsers(count from textbox1.text) and they will stay connected. When clicked to button2 the tasks will closed.

Comment: without the end? `while(true)`? please explain a little bit your intention

Comment: You really should explain what you are trying to achieve. It sounds like you might be approaching the problem from the wrong direction.

Comment: i tried the explain. Not like the endless while. when web browser connected it should not close, disconnect etc. with the other web browsers.

Comment: @ch.nel9 you don't need separate threads with separate webbrowser object, and navigate is async anyway. What do you actually need? Also please apply indentation to your code

Comment: @ch.nel9 this is **not** how SO works. No one is gonna contact you in private. You ask *clear* question that is useful for other users - you get answers. It  is not a place to hire people or ask them to help you in private.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can try.

```
public static object locker =  new object();

    public static void InitBrowser(int browser)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            // Create Browser Here

            Monitor.Wait(locker);
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }

button1.click()
{       
   Monitor.Enter(locker);
   for(int i = 0;i <= converttoint32(textbox1.text);i++)
    InitBrowser(textbox2.text);
}

button2.click()
{
    Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
}
```

You can try this. This solution is not tested, but maybe you could use it like a base to build waht you want.

Comment: Does this run in asynchronous (threads running at the same time) or does one task wait for the other to finish before running?

Comment: @chfumero no, it just schedules task to thread pool, it may be executed without new thread creation by existing thread from thread pool.

Comment: if i use it like that it will not work. Let me explain clearly. 
I want to create web browsers with using this method and they should be unique and work single by single.
eg. textbox1.text = 15; than i will create 15 web browser and they will contuinue working until the button2.click event.

Comment: This is practically useless answer, if you are talking about this WebBrowser https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx then you 1) should not instantiate it once per call 2) naviate is async anyway

Comment: Is true that the Task.Run enqueque the delegate on the thread pool, but it run asynchronously. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. The Task.Run return the reference to the enqueque Task object. You can save it into a list and handle it from there. I will post an edition using the System.Threading.Thread class in a moment.